# MVC- passing string from servlet to business logic code

Tags: java

we're trying to implement mvc in this java code. We're trying to pass a string from the servlet to another java file by creating an object for the other java file's class. So, that is where we are getting the error. I have commented on that line as: throwing error.It would be great if someone could check the code and let us know how to rectify it.

```
 public class BasicSearch extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException
 {
    String word=null;

    word= request.getParameter("keyword");
    String phrase = word;
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);

    SearchService searchservice=new SearchService();
    int[] result=searchservice.basicSearch(String tokens[]);//throwing error
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
     basicSearch(String tokens[])
```

to

```
     basicSearch(tokens)
```